# Viewing a deleted file that was tracked by Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

If I have a file tracked by Mercurial, and delete it:

```
$ rm foo
$ hg status
! foo
```

Is there a way I can view the contents of `foo` without `hg revert`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the contents of a file by using `hg cat <file>` command with the optional revision option:

```
hg cat -r [rev] [filename]
```

You could then pipe that output to a temp file for review. For example on Windows you could do:

```
hg cat -r [rev] [filename] > C:\temp\tempfile.txt
```

---

Your other option depends on your diff viewer. Since I use BC3, I can do an `hg diff -r 1:[rev] [filename]` and one side of my viewer is the file contents I'm looking for.